# Rails, list by integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have a link which routes to a view that lists all of my Users by a given letter, if i click 'A' it displays all my users whose names start with the letter a. How do I do this for users that start with an integer? I assume I'd have to change my params value but I dont know how to do this. this is my code:

```
<%= link_to 'A', users_charlist_path(:char => "A") %>
```

right now I have this but it doesnt work:

```
<%= link_to '#', users_charlist_path(:char => /[0-9]+(\%7C[0-9]+)*/) %>
```

this is my controller:

```
def charlist
  @a = User.all(:conditions => "goal like '#{params[:char]}%'")
end
```

Comment: Could you add the method `charlist` of the controller to the question ?

Answer (score 0):

I think everything must work. Only few moments.

1. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '7%' ...` Works so I think problem with link generation.
2. never pass parameters like this `"#{params}"`. Because it's not secure. Use  `:conditions => ['goal like ?", "#{params[:char]}%"]`
3. try your code in console and use pry for debugging.

Comment: i dont get anything returned with this code though even though i know i have users whose names start with an integer

Comment: what is returning to you User.all(:conditions => ["goal like ?", "#{query}%"]), where query = 7 for example

Comment: Hey @IgorKasyanchuk i am little bit curious about the line `never pass parameters like this "#{params}". Because it's not secure. Use - :conditions => ['goal like ?", "#{params[:char]}%"]` can you explain that .

Comment: sure, just read about SQL Injection here  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: when i search for an individual number it works, but not for any integer

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[0123456789]` as wildcard that can be used by any database ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)).

```
<%= link_to '#', users_charlist_path(:char => '[0123456789]' %>
```

In the controller, as explained by Igor, do not include params directly in the string, that's a security issue

```
def charlist
  @a = User.where('goal like ?', "#{params[:char]}%").to_a
end
```

Comment: hey I think there is a bracket on the end thats missing, unfortunately i dont get anything returned in my view. any thought?

Comment: it works when i search for individual numbers like '9', but it doesnt with the brackets, for instance, '[9]', and likewise with the wildcard